# Post data security in PHP using prepared statement

Tags: php, jquery, html, prepared-statement

I am using a prepared statement for submitting the form using ajax. I tried the below code which is working. I need to know some securities. I checked on google and found some answers and made the below code.

I want to know my post data is correct? Do I need to `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`?

I entered `<h1>naren</h1>` and `naren's` and submitted. Below is database output.

**Database output**

[image]

I got slash `(/)` and apostrophy in the last row.

**Process.php**

```
function register($conn){
    global $currentdate;
    $name=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
    $country=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country']));
    $mobileno=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mobileno']));
    $email=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));

    if($name == "") {
        $errorMsg="Name field is required";
        $code="1";
    } else if($country == "") {
        $errorMsg="Country field is required";
        $code="2";
    } elseif ($mobileno=="") {
        $errorMsg="Mobile number is required";
        $code="3";
    } elseif (is_numeric(trim($mobileno))==false) {
        $errorMsg="Only contain a number";
        $code="3";
    } elseif (strlen($mobileno)<10) {
        $errorMsg="Contain minimun 10 number ex:9892555555";
         $code="3";
    } elseif (strlen($mobileno)>10) {
        $errorMsg="Contain maximum 10 number ex:9892555555";
        $code="3";
    } elseif ($email =="") {
        $errorMsg="Email filed is required";
        $code="4";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)) {
        $errorMsg="Please enter valid email id";
        $code="4";
    } else {
        $query="INSERT INTO `register` (name, country, mobileno, email ,date_of_added) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("sisss", 
                                $name,$country,$mobileno,
                                $email,$currentdate);
            $stmt->execute();
            $errorMsg="Data Inserted";
            $code="5";
            $_SESSION['thankyouSession'] = "true";
        }else{
            $code= "6";
            $errorMsg='Something is wrong';
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
    $response['error']=$errorMsg;
    $response['error_no']=$code;
    echo json_encode($response); 
 }
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#register").validate({
    rules: {
        name:{required:true,minlength:3},
        country:{required:true},
        mobileno:{required:true,minlength:10,maxlength:10,number: true},
        email:{required:true,email: true}
    },

    submitHandler: function (r) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "/process.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#register').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.error_no == '1') {
                    $('#name').html(response.error);
                } else if (response.error_no == '2') {
                    $('#country').html(response.error);
                } else if (response.error_no == '3') {
                    $('#mobileno').html(response.error);
                } else if (response.error_no == '4') {
                    $('#email').html(response.error);
                } else if (response.error_no == '6') {
                    $('#failed').html(response.error);
                }else{
                    window.location.href=base_url+"/thankyou.php";
                }
            }
        })
      }
    });
```

**Database connection**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: `global $currentdate;` Why does that sound like such a bad thing to do, someone help me out here

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I added the timezone code before the function. So I added global $currentdate;

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Your script is open to SQL Injection Attack. I need to know where I am wrong in this with my code? I checked the 
6 revs, 4 users 78%
Danijel  answer

Comment: Thats why that comment has 4 different links in it, so you can go off and have a good read

Comment: If you are using a prepare'd statement, you do not need to escape the data. Thats one of the prime functions of preparing a query. The prepare sends the query to the database and compiles and optimizes it. So when you bind data before an expecute, that data cannot effect the execution of the query like it could if you were concatenating values into a string and then executing the string

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Ok, I got your last comment. I removed $conn->real_escape_string

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439

Answer (score 0):

As far I know you don't need real_escape_string with prepared statements.

For the POST varables you maybe better can use isset, like:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) : '';
```

To prevent undefined errors

$country needs to be an integer when i take a look at your query.

```
$country= isset($_POST['country']) ? (int)$_POST['country']) : 0;
```

And then in the elseif check if $country > 0

For email check you can also use:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
// No valid email
}
```

And maybe after excecute check for affected rows te be sure the data is really inserted.

A sanitize function can be necessary for showing the database results in your html

Comment: _As far I know you don't need real_escape_string with prepared statements._ So why does your next line escape the inputs

Comment: I copied his code, for the insert or update its not necessary